# wpf local and external binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a custom control with two DependencyProperties. One of type object, which allows the user to add custom content like other controls and one of type string which is used in a Textbox:

```
public object NoResultContent
{
    get { return (object)GetValue(NoResultContentProperty); }
    set { SetValue(NoResultContentProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty NoResultContentProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("NoResultContent", typeof(object), typeof(AdvancedAutoCompleteBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public string FilterText
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(FilterTextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FilterTextProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterTextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("FilterText", typeof(string), typeof(AdvancedAutoCompleteBox),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal,
                        new PropertyChangedCallback(OnFilterTextPropertyChanged), new CoerceValueCallback(CoerceText),
                        true, UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged));
```

The `ControlTemplate` looks like:

```
<ControlTemplate
    TargetType="{x:Type local:SpecialBox}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox
            Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=FilterText}" />
        <ContentPresenter
            ContentSource="NoResultContent" />
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I'm using it like this:

```
<Controls:SpecialBox
    Name="Box">
    <Controls:SpecialBox.NoResultContent>
        <Button
            Content="Add value"
            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Box, Path=FilterText}"
            Command="{Binding AddProject}" />
    </Controls:SpecialBox.NoResultContent>
</Controls:SpecialBox>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Box, Path=FilterText}" />
```

The `DataContext` of my `Window` is set to my ViewModel. So Binding to the `ICommand` works. Providing a constant string as a CommandParameter will pass it as desired to the ICommand.

```
CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Content}"
```

will pass "Add value" to my ICommand implementation.

The ElementName Binding, as stated above and following code
    CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Controls:SpeicalBox}, Path=FilterText}"

does not work. The source can not be found.

CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=FilterText}"

does not throw a warning, but always return null.

Further info:
The OnFilterTextPropertyChanged Event of my dp is fired on each change. So the value is available, that's why the `TextBlock`s Text Binding to the SpecialBox works quite well.

Providing a second Property on my ViewModel for the FilterText value would be a workaround, but how am I able to access the local dp from that second property?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What is the command parameter your command is getting?

Comment: The Binding always return null. Writing a constant string value as a parameter works fine

Comment: First you need to establish whether `Button.CommandParameter` is actually `null` or not (the fault might just as well be in bad `ICommand` implementation). E.g. add a `Button.Click` handler, set a breakpoint and inspect the `Button`.

Comment: ICommand works well. The actual problem, is that any Element or relative binding does not work: Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='Controls.SpecialBox', AncestorLevel='1''

Comment: Ok then. In that case is the code you're provided the actual template that you're using (in particular the `ContentPresenter`)? Also, what framework version are you using?

Comment: Yes the ContentPresenter is as provided. Framework: 4.5 and I also tried 4.6.1

Comment: Ok, I've tested a ContentControl instead of the Presenter... And now, the Elementbinding and RelativeSource AncestorType works :) Thanks for the impulse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the ContenPresenter to a ContentControl did the trick

```
<ContentControl
    Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=NoResultContent}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way of binding in this case is to use `RelativeSource` in `FindAncestor` mode:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding FilterText,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Controls:SpeicalBox}}"
```

Also, using `ElementName` should work fine.

Now why it does not work is because you're using `TemplateBinding` on the `TextBox` in your template. The `TemplateBinding` works one-way, so whatever you type in the `TextBox` is not pushed back to your `FilterText` property (it was designed to forward properties like `Background`, `BorderBrush` etc. to the template more efficiently by being resolved at compile-time unlike normal bindings, which are resolved at run-time). So what you need to do is to replace it with a normal binding with `RelativeSource` in `TemplatedParent` mode in your template:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FilterText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
```

That at least is what resolved the problem I've managed to reproduce based on the code you've provided (and it was my first suspicion). It does however stand in contradiction to your claim that the binding on the `TextBlock` did actually work. So I suggest you try this out and get back if it does not solve your problem.

Comment: Honest speaking, I access the Text Property of the Control template by Template.FindName in OnApplyTemplate(). The example I've provided was just to ease up the question. But you're right. It must be RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}} in order for a working example. My fault, sorry. I'll edit my question.